# RxSwift: share() alternative that guarantees single subscription on the upstream

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I've always thought `.share(replay: 1, scope: .forever)` shares the single upstream subscription no matter how many downstream subscribers there are.

However, I've just discovered that if the count of the downstream subscriptions drops to zero, it stops "sharing" and releases the subscription on the upstream (because `refCount()` is used under the hood). So when a new downstream subscription happens, it has to **re-subscribe** on the upstream. In the following example:

```swift
let sut = Observable<Int>
    .create { promise in
        print("create")
        promise.onNext(0)
        return Disposables.create()
    }
    .share(replay: 1, scope: .forever)

sut.subscribe().dispose()
sut.subscribe().dispose()
```

I would expect `create` to be printed just once, but it gets printed twice. And if I remove `.dispose()` calls - just once.

How do I set up the chain where the upstream is guaranteed to be subscribed at most once?

Comment: Look's like bug for me. Can suggest to use `deferred` and return `just` like in the comments for `.forever` scope.

Comment: `promise.onCompleted()` fixes output. May be it's connected to `replay: 1`: when there is no output and stream isn't completed, then it's nothing to replay.

Comment: Well, I cannot use `onCompleted()` in my code because I'm starting a DB change observation in the `create` block, this stream does not  "complete"

Comment: >nothing to replay.< yeah, but even if you send a value the issue would stay. I'll update the code to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't like the leaking `Disposable` in the suggested solutions so came up with the following:

```swift
extension ObservableType {
    func shareReplayForever() -> Observable<Element> {
        let relay = BehaviorRelay<Element?>(value: nil)
        let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
        var subscribeOnce: () -> Void = {
            self.bind(to: relay).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        }
        return relay
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .do(onSubscribe: {
                subscribeOnce()
                subscribeOnce = { }
            }, onDispose: {
                _ = disposeBag
            })
    }
}
```

The trick is to capture the `disposeBag` in a downstream closure `onDispose`. As long as any code is holding a reference to the downstream observable (thus being capable to subscribe in the future), the `disposeBag` stays alive. However, it does get disposed when all the downstream observables are deallocated (no one down the stream can subscribe anymore - we can release the upstream)

Answer (score 1):

The goal you describe implies you should be using `multicast` (or one of operators that use it, like `publish()`, `replay(_:)` or `replayAll()`) and not `share`...

```
let sut = Observable<Int>
    .create { observer in
        print("create")
        observer.onNext(0)
        return Disposables.create()
    }
    .replay(1)

let disposable = sut.connect() // subscription will stay alive until dispose() is called on this disposable...

sut.debug("one").subscribe().dispose()
sut.debug("two").subscribe().dispose()
```

To understand the difference between .forever and .whileConnected, read the documentation in the "ShareReplayScope.swift" file. Both are refcounted, but the difference is in how re-subscription operators are handled. Here is some test code to show the difference...

```
class SandboxTests: XCTestCase {
    var scheduler: TestScheduler!
    var observable: Observable<String>!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
        // creates an observable that will error on the first subscription, then call `.onNext("A")` on the second.
        observable = scheduler.createObservable(timeline: "-#-A")
    }

    func testWhileConnected() {
        // this shows that re-subscription gets through the while connected share to the source observable
        let result = scheduler.start { [observable] in
            observable!
                .share(scope: .whileConnected)
                .retry(2)
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(result.events, [
            .next(202, "A")
        ])
    }

    func testForever() {
        // however re-subscription doesn't get through on a forever share
        let result = scheduler.start { [observable] in
            observable!
                .share(scope: .forever)
                .retry(2)
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(result.events, [
            .error(201, NSError(domain: "Test Domain", code: -1))
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why `.share(replay: 1, scope: .forever)` is not giving the behaviour you want (I also think it should work like you describe) but what about this other way without `share`?

```swift
// You will subscribe to this and not directly on sut (maybe hiding Subject interface to avoid onNext calls from observers)
let subject = ReplaySubject<Int>.create(bufferSize: 1)

let sut = Observable<Int>.create { obs in
  print("Performing work ...")
  obs.onNext(0)
  return Disposables.create()
}

// This subscription is hidden, happens only once and stays alive forever
sut.subscribe(subject)

// Observers subscribe to the public stream
subject.subscribe().dispose()
subject.subscribe().dispose()
```

Comment: I ended up with a similar code for now, where I intentionally "leak" a subscription. I'm not a fan of this, that's why was hoping there is a cleaner approach